# How to add hours in datetime in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

I want to add hours in DateTime. I have googled it but couldn't find any code.

Here is this datetime `2018-07-25 20:23:22`. I want to add hours in this datetime so it gives me new datetime in the same format

I have tried this.

```
var datetime = "2018-07-25 20:23:22";
datetime.setHours(datetime.getHours()+5);
```

But It didn't work.

Comment: You'll need to have your `datetime` as a `Date` object

Comment: Consider https://momentjs.com/ library for date manipulations.

Comment: Also, "It didn't work" is *really* not enough information - please share what exactly happened - did you get any errors?

Comment: Your `datetime` is a String. Setting hours on a String doesn't make any sense - as Lix suggests, `datetime` needs to be a `Date`.

Comment: @JamesWhiteley how can I do it then?

Comment: `new Date("2018-07-25 20:23:22")`

Answer (score 18):

Your `datetime` is `String`. You need to convert it into `Date` object first.

```js
var datetime = new Date("2018-07-25 20:23:22");
console.log("Before: ", datetime);
datetime.setHours(datetime.getHours()+1); 
console.log("After: ", datetime);
```

I would prefer to use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) library for manipulating and playing with dates.

Hope this may help you.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the simple way with using Moment.js

```
const date = moment('2018-07-25 20:23:22');
date.add(5, 'h');
console.log(date.toString());
```